# Autodesk Forge Viewer: how to set object occlusion

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm playing around with the Autodesk forge viewer and adding custom elements, like it is done in the Autodesk's [scene builder example](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer).

I am looking for a possibility to set the "visibility" of one of the new objects - e.g. when moving around the camera, the green cube should remain on it's 3D-position but should not be occluded by any other object (like it is somehow in blue with outline when it is selected). Or maybe even better: if it is covered by another object, it should shine through (with configurable opacity).

Comment: I had success with `depthTest` set to false once but somehow couldn't get it to work anymore ... I am getting a hold of our Engineering for input so in the meantime try adding the geometry to overlay scenes as a workaround

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately after discussing with Engineering it's not yet possible - will continue the conversation to see if we could come up with a workaround for the upcoming releases ...

Like I suggested in the comments try append your geometry to `Viewer3DImpl.sceneAfter` for the time being (which will be publicly documented and exposed as Viewer3D.sceneAfter in a couple of weeks) or an overlay. Then setting `depthTest` to false should do what you want...

The choice of sceneAfter or an overlay depends on how you want the objects to be drawn during progressive rendering. sceneAfter is only drawn once at the end of everything else. Overlays are redrawn for each progressive frame...